# Sample from dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset and I want to sample from it but with a conditional.  What I need is a new dataframe with the almost the same amount (count) of values of a boolean column of `0 and 1'

**What I have:**

```
df['target'].value_counts()

0 = 4000
1 = 120000
```

**What I need:**

```
new_df['target'].value_counts()

0 = 4000
1 = 6000
```

I know I can df.sample but I dont know how to insert the conditional.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.1.0, you can use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) if you need the same number of rows for each group:

```
df.groupby('target').sample(4000)
```

*Demo*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0] * 10 + [1] * 25})

df.groupby('x').sample(5)
x
8   0
6   0
7   0
2   0
9   0
18  1
33  1
24  1
32  1
15  1
```

---

If you need to sample conditionally based on the group value, you can do:

```
df.groupby('target', group_keys=False).apply(
  lambda g: g.sample(4000 if g.name == 0 else 6000)
)
```

*Demo*:

```
df.groupby('x', group_keys=False).apply(
  lambda g: g.sample(4 if g.name == 0 else 6)
)
x
7   0
8   0
2   0
1   0
18  1
12  1
17  1
22  1
30  1
28  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following input and using the values 4/6 instead of 4000/6000:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'target': [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]})
```

You could `groupby` your target and `sample` to take at most N values per group:

```
df.groupby('target', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.sample(min(len(g), 6)))
```

example output:

```
    target
4        0
0        0
8        0
12       0
10       1
14       1
1        1
7        1
11       1
13       1
```

If you want the same size you can simply use `df.groupby('target').sample(n=4)`